# Cancel loading in WebView on Android

Tags: android, webview

How can I cancel a loading operation in `WebView` started by `loadData()` method?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

[**`stopLoading`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#stopLoading%28%29) will stop the current load.

Comment: Damn, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us.

Comment: Just be a ware that if you have your webview inside a fragment and you use WebViewClient for showing custom loading progress bar, onPageFinished will be called even if your fragment's onDestroyView get called. so check if your progress bar is not null to avoid null pointer exception.

Comment: stopLoading is deprecated

Comment: @NaveedAhmad nope 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a8352f4/core/java/android/webkit/WebView.java#1049
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a8352f4/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewProvider.java#129

Comment: Hi @user3193413 if we use kotlin, binding.progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE will give warning unnecessary safe call on a non-null receiver