# What does stopLoading() really do?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

Yes, I know the documentation for [stopLoading()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#stopLoading%28%29) says "*Stops the current load.*"

But when I try to use it to stop loading currently progressing page before loading a new one, it doesn't seem to behave [as desired](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3679080/1088880):

```
07-24 12:53:30.177: V/WebView.loadUrl: http://www.google.com
07-24 12:53:30.227: V/WebViewClient.onPageStarted: http://www.google.com

===> WebView.stopLoading() called here <====

07-24 12:53:31.917: V/WebView.loadUrl: http://www.stackoverflow.com
07-24 12:53:32.697: V/WebViewClient.onPageFinished: http://www.google.com

07-24 12:53:32.767: V/WebViewClient.onPageStarted: http://www.stackoverflow.com
07-24 12:53:33.587: V/WebViewClient.onPageFinished: http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

As you can see in the log, `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()` for the first `loadUrl()` gets called despite the fact that `WebView.stopLoading()` was called about **1 second earlier**.

Why is that?

What does [stopLoading()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2223068/1088880) really do?

Comment: I'm guessing it just sets a flag to tell the WebView not to run any of the hooks like onPageFinished, etc. I don't think it will actually stop the network connection.

Answer (score 5):

you786 is right:

```
public void stopLoading() {
    checkThread();
    // TODO: should we clear all the messages in the queue before sending
    // STOP_LOADING?
    switchOutDrawHistory();
    mWebViewCore.sendMessage(EventHub.STOP_LOADING);
}
```

For that TODO they marked in the remaining messages would get processed in first. So that results in what I am just curious about: when stopping load in

```
WebViewClient.onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
```

The WebView does not really stops, instead it loads its own 404 Page (what it normally would do if you don't call stopLoading()):

```
11-07 16:30:01.112: I/MainActivity(19189): Loading: http://92.53.45.42
11-07 16:30:01.253: V/MainActivity.WebViewClient(19189): SHOULD_INTERCEPT_REQUEST: http://92.53.45.42/
11-07 16:30:01.347: V/MainActivity.WebViewClient(19189): PAGE_STARTED: http://92.53.45.42/
11-07 16:30:01.347: V/MainActivity.WebChromeClient(19189): ON_PROGRESS_CHANGED: 10
11-07 16:30:01.347: V/MainActivity.WebViewClient(19189): LOAD_RESOURCE: http://92.53.45.42/
11-07 16:30:25.292: I/GATE(19189): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_ERROR</GATE-M>
11-07 16:30:25.300: E/MainActivity.WebViewClient(19189): (CONNECT - Failed to connect to the server) -> http://92.53.45.42/
11-07 16:30:25.300: W/MainActivity.WebViewClient(19189): loading stopped..:
11-07 16:30:25.300: V/MainActivity.WebViewClient(19189): PAGE_STARTED: http://92.53.45.42/
11-07 16:30:25.300: I/MainActivity.WebViewClient(19189): PAGE_FINISHED: http://92.53.45.42/
11-07 16:30:25.339: I/MainActivity.WebChromeClient(19189): ON_RECEIVED_TITLE: Webseite nicht verfügbar
11-07 16:30:25.339: V/MainActivity.WebChromeClient(19189): GET_VISITED_HISTORY
11-07 16:30:25.339: I/GATE(19189): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
11-07 16:30:25.339: V/MainActivity.WebChromeClient(19189): ON_PROGRESS_CHANGED: 100
11-07 16:30:25.339: I/MainActivity.WebViewClient(19189): PAGE_FINISHED: http://92.53.45.42/
```